# How can I get condor collector to run

Tags: cluster-computing, centos8, condor

I have installed HTcondor on my cluster of Dell Optiplex 390s they all are running Centos 8 and I am not able to run condor_status I get the following error --> Error: can't find collector

I am new to using condor and all I want to be able to do is have a master node that can manage jobs and execute them and for the rest to just execute the jobs. I have opened port 9618/tcp on all the nodes to run the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well there are two possibilities:  One, the collector isn't running, and two, it is running, but condor_status can't find it.

Let's start with potential problem number one.  If you run

ps auxww | grep condor_collector

on you machine that should be the central manager, is there a collector process running?

If so, that's good.

problem 2 is to set the condor_config variable COLLECTOR_HOST to point to this machine e.g.

COLLECTOR_HOST = my_central_manager

Comment: I have added the variable but I get this ERROR now  SECMAN:2007:Failed to end classad message                                                                                                                              
 This is my some of my condor_config file    ##  The normal way to do configuration with RPMs is to read all of the
##  files in a given directory that don't match a regex as configuration files.
##  Config files are read in lexicographic order.
LOCAL_CONFIG_DIR = /etc/condor/config.d
CONDOR_HOST = 10.3.60.196
COLLECTOR_HOST = $(CONDOR_HOST)